# 'Purchase currency not supported' when using in app billing and a test user account in google play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm using a test google checkout account I created using a credit card number from here: https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox

When I try to buy something in app from an unpublished app (the item itself is published) using the test account it requests I add a credit card, if I go to the drop down to select an existing card it shows the card from the aforementioned link I had added but says 'purchase currency is not supported'.

Answer (score 0):

From http://mobility.forumsee.com/a/m/s/p12-22971-0373237--solved-purchase-currency-not-supported-error-when-buying-app.html

edit: AMEX works on Google Play only for purchases denominated in USD.

==

I had the same problem, switching to AMEX to VISA and that worked.